# Sending commands to nor flash

Tags: c, linux, embedded

In my embedded target , the NOR flash overlays the address map after some commands with status,device info , cfi info etc.

To read the normal adresses i use :

```
map= (int *)(mmap(0,SECTOR_SIZE*NUM_SECTORS,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,_fdmem,NOR_FLASH_PHYS));
printf("Location 0x0 , data %x\n",map[0]);
```

To switch to the overlay mode i have to preform somw writes :

```
ID (Autoselect) Entry  555 AA 2AA 55 555 90
```

(chip is S29GL128S)
but :

```
map[0x555]=0xAA;
map[0x2AA]=0x55;
map[0x555]=0x90;
```

Does not work.Still reads the normal memory instead of chip id.

Reading /dev/mem with lseek and read returns 0..so guess writing that way won't work also.

Kind of newbee in this area and c..so all help is welcome.

thanks

Comment: Any reason why you can't do `*(volatile uint32_t*)0x555 = 0xAA` and skip all the weird, non-standard stuff?

Comment: @Lundin - because that is not the address of the chip in the process memory space.  The point of the mmap is to map the physical device into a logical address, which must then be used as the base for access.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use casting to (int **)? What is the type of variable map, int**? sizeof(int) == 4, so map[0x555] means map[0x555*4 bytes] in memory. Use casting to (unsigned char *) or (uint8_t).

May be the error is somewhere there.

Comment: You may have a point here, but it is not fully worked out.  The device appears to have a 16-bit data bus.  If the processor treats it as 16-bit memory, then addresses will be "true" and byte offsets would be consistent with an unsigned char *.  But if a 16-bit memory is connected to a 32-bit processor which believes it is 32-bit, then, every other 16-bit word will be unused, and addressing will be tricky.

Comment: Not sure why i used int *..it was just a copy/paste from a script from the web. Your comment made me think about the 16 vs 32 bit issue. since results i get beack when i read a location are 32 bit's..i guess it uses 32 bit.. the addresses given are 16bit..so tried 2AA and 155 as addresses. but no luck.i'm afried i should make a kernel module.(little bit out of my league..since i first used c about a week ago :-)

Comment: @arnold: Could you share your C-code and describe what exactly you what it to do?